# should the mutexlocker be both added into two functions where they tried to visit and write the same variable from different thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qmutex

Here is a global variable:

```
extern int i;
```

Two threads *A* & *B* try to visit and write the variable *i*, the function in thread *A* just as beneath:

```
void funA(int *i)
{
    QMutexLocker(&m_mutex);  //to lock the process
    *i += 5;
}
```

and thread *B* process function:

```
void funB(int *i)
{
    QMutexLocker(&m_mutex);  //**should I add this?**
    *i -= 2;
}
```

There are two threads which visit only one variable, should I add *QMutexLocker* into two functions or only add one ? Could I just add one ?

Comment: Where is m_mutex defined? It must be the same instance for all access to i. I'd also avoid global variables and make mutex and variable a member of some class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `QMutexLocker` in both your functions.